# .NET NativeWifi cell phone detection

Tags: .net, vb.net, wifi

I am looking for a .NET solution similar to PERL hcitool and the hoover.pl script for PERL, in which cell phone SSID and RSSI information can be acquired. I know about NativeWiFi wrapper for C#, but it seems like such a vast implementation, with nothing explicitly trying to identify MAC addresses and create transit vectors. Specifically, I would like to:

(a) have in place AP devices like Ubiquity PicoStation series APs
(b) enter into a passive listening mode for Beacon requests (see https://github.com/xme/hoover)
(c) identify MAC, RSSI

within a .NET environment. I need to

1. establish a connection
2. listen for beacon requests to obtain MAC and RSSI

For contextual reference see Musa et al. at http://www.engr.uic.edu/pub/Bits/Musa/musa-eriksson-sensys12.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It probably isn't profitable to approach the problem of reading probe requests and beacons from the NativeWiFi class. Instead, I am going to approach it from packet capture side instead, using the WinPCap library and possibly tshark (which currently doesn't hold all captures and cause memory overflow) and use capture filters such as wlan.fc.type_subtype eq 4 (for probe requests).